# How to open several csv files from a larger file into code?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file

Okay so I have a file that inside of it has 1000 csv files. So instead of having to pull 500 csv files, I was wondering what code could be written that could pull all of the csv files, then append them to a list.
Imagine something like:

```
csv_file_list = []    

for csv in big_file:
    csv_file_list.append(csv)
```

So this is what Im trying to do, now obviosly this would provide an error, so my question is what would be a way to code this correctly?

Comment: file containing 1000 CSV files or 1000 CSV file paths?

Comment: file containing 1000 csv paths, each path which have datasets in them

Comment: You have to read CSV files in a loop & append its data in list..

Comment: Could you show a code that would do that?Do I read them with the pandas read_csv function?

Comment: what is the format of your file? you will need to give an example to get help

Comment: What do you mean by format? Like what is the path of the file?

Comment: like how your big file lines, separators, etc is looking

Comment: Its just a file, and in it there is a list of csv paths that all of datasets in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
dataset = []

folder_path = 'path to your folder here in commas'

for csv in os.listdir(folder_path):
    dataset.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path,csv)))
```

Comment: Okay but like how do I call the big file? So say the path is - Users/benitocano/Desktop/Mega Package Data/us_1500_tickers_A_C_hgj7gj. How do I write that in a way so that the computer can understand?

Comment: is your big file also csv?

Comment: No it is a folder

Comment: check my code now. you have to write path in 4th line, inside ' ' these comma

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Is this the idea?

```
numCSVFILES = 10
csv_paths = ['/'.join(['part%d%d'%(j,i) for i in range(3)])+'/csvfile%d.csv'%j for j in range(numCSVFILES)]
with open('junk.txt','w') as fio:
    fio.write('\n'.join(csv_paths))

with open('junk.txt','r') as fio:
    csv2_paths = fio.read().split('\n')

print(csv2_paths)
```

Output

```
['part00/part01/part02/csvfile0.csv', 'part10/part11/part12/csvfile1.csv', 'part20/part21/part22/csvfile2.csv', 'part30/part31/part32/csvfile3.csv', 'part40/part41/part42/csvfile4.csv', 'part50/part51/part52/csvfile5.csv', 'part60/part61/part62/csvfile6.csv', 'part70/part71/part72/csvfile7.csv', 'part80/part81/part82/csvfile8.csv', 'part90/part91/part92/csvfile9.csv']
```